# Rendering a pdf in a different location, from a standalone tex-file that combines several chapters

Tags: graphics, pdftex, include, nesting

I've seen a lot of these questions, but in my search I haven't managed to find an answer to my problem. I am building a directory system for simple use, where I have divided the first folder into "Parts" and "Results". In the Parts directory, I have folders called "Tex", "Img" and "Combo".

Tex contains four different `tex` files, chapters. Img contains all images from every chapter. I want all images in one location because some of them appear more than once. If I need to replace one of the images I want it to do so everywhere where it appears. Combo contains the `tex` file which combines the four chapters into one big book, of sorts. I use the package `standalone` to rid the chapters from their preamble and to make it a main file. I then use `\include` with a relative path to the different chapter-files that I want to include.

Going back to the root folder of this directory-system, the other folder is called "Results". This is where I want all of the rendered content (`html` and `pdf`). The reason why I am building the system this way is because I am not the end user of the files, which means it should be simple to navigate and understand.

**The problem I have** appears when I want to use `pdflatex` to compile the main file. A lot of what I understand is called "nesting" is happening here. I'm rendering the results in the "Results"-folder, which fetches information from the `tex`in the "Combo"-folders which in turn retrieves files from the "Tex"-folder. All of these chapters then wants images from the "Img"-folder.

I get these errors in the terminal when trying the `pdflatex` command while working in the "Results"-directory:

```
! LaTeX Error: File `../tex/Chapter1.tex' not found.

Type X to quit or <RETURN> to proceed,
or enter new name. (Default extension: tex)

Enter file name:
```

If I enter the absolute path to the Chapter1-file

```
Enter file name: /Users/Rikardny/Documents/temp/Assets/tex/Chapter1.tex
```

I instead get the error

```
! Package pdftex.def Error: File `login.jpg' not found.

See the pdftex.def package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.48 ...degraphics[width=0.8\textwidth]{login.jpg}

?
```

I understand this is a problem because of the relative paths to other files in each of the documents. Whilst in the "Results"-directory, the relative paths point to a different place than in the "Combo"-directory. However I would like to use relative paths because the folders are going to move to different machines later. Is there a way to maintain the directory-system but not change all the relative paths to absolute paths?

Comment: If the filenames are unique then you could add the top directory to your TEXINPUTS environment variable and add `//` after it so that tex will search subdirectories: `export TEXINPUTS="....:My_Directory//:..."`. This should work for *unix-like systems.

Comment: See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/49488/changing-the-working-directory-when-including-files-in-a-subdirectory

Comment: @Andrew How exactly do I do this? Does it work with images as well? The question which i duplicated does not answer this question on a level that I can understand really...

Comment: @Rikardny What operating system (and shell) do you use?

Comment: @Andrew I use OS X and bash. Does using your method work on every machine that the file-system is moved to? Or is it specific for my computer?

Comment: In your `.bashrc` or `.bash_profile` you need to modify the definition of the `TEXINPUTS` environment variable. If it isn't already there then add the line: `export TEXINPUTS=".:~/path/to/your/top/directory//:". If is already defined in your `.bash*` file then add `~/path/to/your/top/directory//:` to the end. Note that the trailing : is essential as it tells (la)TeX to search the system directories . The trailing `//` says to look in subdirectories. From any NEW shell (la)TeX will now ALWAYS search in these directories for the files it cannot find.

Comment: ...btw as I said, exporting TEXINPUTS as above means that TeX will ALWAYS search these directories, which may not be what you want. You can "localise" this with bash function:
`function my_pdflatex() {(export TEXINPUTS=".:~/path/to/your/top/directory//:" && pdflatex "$@")}`

Comment: @Andrew Okay, that worked! Altough it's complicated to repeat the process on each computer which I'd like the folders to be on. I'm gonna try setting up some symbolic links and use every command in the root directory instead, thanks though!