# How can I save and restore \graphicspath

Tags: graphics

I want to include snippets (with their images in a dir with the same name as the tex file) from a shared repository in the `content` directory. I have defined a command for that:

```
\newcommand*{\includecontent}[1]{\graphicspath{{./content/#1/}}%
\input{./content/#1}}
```

My problem: This resets the graphicspath defined in the processed file. Is there

- either a way to add a path to graphicspath without disturbing the existing ones
- or (preferred) to save the current graphicspath before and restore it after the snippet was included

Comment: I normally use something like `\begingroup\graphicspath{...} \input... \endgroup` jo just add begin/endgroup inside your macro definition

Comment: Wonderful, that saves me a lot of clutter, thank you :-)